# transfering rewards from website to crypto wallet

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, ether, ethers.js

I want to transfer rewards that user had earn to his crypto wallet but problem is in our smart contract there is function with parameter value(amount) and address of reciever I need a secure way of passing these perimeters to smart contract from website.

Comment: Could you share a code snippet and document your issue more precisely?

Comment: its a transfer function of erc721 with parameters (amount, recipent_address) now I want a secure way to call this function in our Unreal engine 4 game or on our website I have a knowledge of etherjs webjs but looking for a way that makes it least vulnerable @PaulRazvanBerg

Comment: If you have a backend you could sign an authrization message that the user has to send, then the contract will validate the signature is valid and the sender and amount matches the signed message and mint the tokens otherwise it will revert.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more I did not got the flow @Ismael